# How do you get an Angular directive to auto-refresh when loading data asynchronously?

Tags: angularjs

I've been creating a number of small directives and using hard-coded arrays for testing while I build out functionality. Now that I've got some of that done, I went back and created a service to load the data from a website via JSON; it returns a promise and when it's successful I update the property my template is based off of. Of course, as soon as I did that my directive stopped rendering correctly.

What is the preferred way of binding my directive to asynchronously loaded data so that when the data finally comes back my directive renders?

I'm using Angular 1.4.7.

Here's a simple example of my hard-coded version.

```js
angular
    .module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('test', function(){
    var vm = this;
    
    vm.inv = 'B';
    vm.displayInv = function () {        
        alert('inv:' + vm.inv);
    };
});

angular.module('app')
       .directive('inventorytest', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<select ng-model="ctrl.selectedOption" ng-options="inv.code as inv.desc for inv in ctrl.invTypes"></select>{{ctrl.sample}}. Selected: {{ctrl.selectedOption}}',

        scope: { selectedOption: '='},
        bindToController: true,
        controller: function () {
            this.invTypes = [
                { code: 'A', desc: 'Alpha' },
                { code: 'B', desc: 'Bravo' },
                { code: 'C', desc: 'Charlie' },
            ];
            this.sample = 'Hello';
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test as vm">
    <inventorytest selected-option='vm.inv'></inventorytest>
    
    <br/>
    Controller: {{vm.inv}}
</div>
```

My service is essentially just a thin wrapper around an $http call, ex:

```
return $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'https://myurl.com/getinfo' });
```

And I had tried modifying my code to do something like:

```
 this.invTypes = [ { code: '', desc: '' }];
 ctrService.getInfo()
          .then(function successCallback(response) {
                this.invTypes = response.data;
          }, function errorCallback(response) {
           // display error
 });
```

Like I said, that doesn't work since it seems Angular isn't watching this property.

Comment: did you injected the `ctrService`  service?

Comment: can I see your entire directive in your new version

Comment: Yes, I'm injecting ctrService. It's getting called and returning back the JSON result as expected. The code is pretty much as shown in my last example - I replaced the hardcoded this.invTypes array with the code you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the callback  `this` has a different context and isn't what you want it to be.

You need to save a reference to the controller `this` and use that within any callbacks

```
// store reference to `this`
var vm = this;
vm.invTypes = [ { code: '', desc: '' }];
 ctrService.getInfo()
          .then(function successCallback(response) {
                // must use reference to maintain context 
                vm.invTypes = response.data;
          }, function errorCallback(response) {
           // display error
 });
```

Comment: Oh for heavens sake, as often as I had been burned by that in the past you'd think I would have realized that since I do the same thing in my controllers. Yes, this fixed it.